# Django urls.py not working

Tags: python, django, apache

I recently moved my functional Django project over from localhost to my apache2 server and the urls don't seem to work.  When I do something like mysite.com/survey/calcs, it should take me to the 'calcs' page because i defined the calcs path in my urls.py file.

Everything worked when I tried this locally.  I did localhost then /calcs and the page loaded.

Any ideas why urls.py isn't working on my apache server?  I'm using mod_wsgi to put the project up.

Here's what urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

url(r'^calcs', 'pivotviewer.views.RController'),
url(r'^test', 'pivotviewer.views.current_datetime'),
)
```

surveys.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.example.edu
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/surveys/index.wsgi

Alias /static /var/www/surveys/static/

<Directory /var/www/surveys/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then lastly, my index.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/pv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/surveys')
sys.path.append('/var/www/surveys/pv')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'pv.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/pv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I looked at at least 5 tutorials online and their configurations are almost exactly the same as this.  Did I mess up on the project path perhaps?

Comment: what's the error, does it give a 404?

Comment: Show the relevant part of your Apache config too.

Comment: your urls.py seems ok, the problem probably is in the apache config or wsgi.py file.

Comment: Check if you've correctly set up the PythonPath for your WSGIScript.

Comment: It is an occasional mistake by mod_wsgi users when mounting at a sub URL to include a trailing slash on the sub URL given as first argument to the WSGIScriptAlias directive. Make sure you don't do that as it can cause problems. To know for sure, add your mod_wsgi configuration directives.

Comment: It gives a 404 error.  Okay let me edit above to display my conf file in sites-available/ since I never touched wsgi.py.  My project is in /var/www/surveys.